# Hazelcast: listen to seeding from persistence

Tags: dictionary, listener, hazelcast

I have two maps with different keys but same tipe of values i.e. values in these two maps are same objects but a referred to with different keys. Keys are actually attributes of these objects. To reduce amount of stored in persistence objects I implemented map store only for one map (no rationale to store same set of objects twice). Is there a way to populate two different maps from one backed store? I tried with interceptor and entry listener and it seems they don't work at the time when map is being loaded from backed storage.
I'm using Hazelcast 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your second Map to have just MapLoader and not a MapStore.

Comment: @FuadMalikov may you help me with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369352/get-started-with-hazelcast-sourcecode?noredirect=1#comment48830581_30369352 please?